# Issue with downloading Pentaho Kettle jar files from repository

Tags: jar, repository, kettle

I am trying to download kettle jars from the following repository in Maven:

```
  <repository>
        <id>pentaho-rep</id>
        <url>http://maven-repository.com/artifact/pentaho-kettle/</url>
  </repository>
```

but get following file format error during maven build:
    .m2\repository\pentaho\kettle\kettle-core\5.3.0.0-200\kettle-core-5.3.0.0-200.jar; error in opening zip file

I tried deleting .m2, also tried other kettle versions, etc. but same problem. It is not clear to me if the repository is corrupted, or some other issue. Any suggestions or alternate repo location I can use (that contains kettle 5.2 version and above)? There is not much useful help available on Pentaho site or forum on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe we publish our JARs to maven-repository.com.  Try our official repository: http://nexus.pentaho.org/content/groups/omni

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below repo. for getting the files.

`<repository>
        <id>pentaho-releases</id>
        <url>http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/</url>
    </repository>`

It may not be the official pentaho repository. But it worked for me. You may check [this](https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2014/12/29/maven-dependencies-for-building-pentaho-di-kettle-plugins/) ref. blog.

Hope it might help you too :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, the following worked for me:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>pentaho-releases</id>
        <url>http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<properties>
    <pentaho.kettle.version>5.3.0.0-200</pentaho.kettle.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
        <artifactId>kettle-core</artifactId>
        <version>${pentaho.kettle.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
        <artifactId>kettle-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${pentaho.kettle.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
        <artifactId>kettle-ui-swt</artifactId>
        <version>${pentaho.kettle.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently we have faced same issue. with below update repository and version number, maven build is fixed for me.

```
 <repository>
   <id>pentaho-public</id>
   <url>https://repo.orl.eng.hitachivantara.com/artifactory/pnt-mvn/</url>
</repository>
<dependency>
    <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
    <artifactId>kettle-core</artifactId>
    <version>9.5.2.0-272</version>
</dependency>r code here
```